# How to use the value of a string in bash as a variable name

Tags: linux, string, bash

Hopefully I can make it clear. I would like to create a filename out of different strings in `bash`. For example `hmd.sh` so `h`, `m`, `d` are different values (number `0..9` or letter `aA..zZ`). So for example I want to convert

```
h=1 m=11 and d=12 to 1aA.sh. h=> 1, m=>a and d=>A
```

To declare variables like

```
a01=1; a02=2 .. a09=9, a10=0; a11=a; a12=b and so on. h(1)=a01=1 m(11)=a11=a
```

and

```
d(12)=a12=A.
```

To test it I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dd01="1"
aa="01"
bb="dd$aa"
echo $bb
```

But of course `$bb` is `dd01` and not its value. How can I make `$bb` its value of 1?

Answer (score 4):

Associative arrays make this kind of thing much more readable.

However your answer is "variable indirection"

```
$ echo $bb
dd01
$ echo ${!bb}
1
```

Do not listen to any advice suggesting `eval` -- you open yourself up to all kinds of code injection.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to expand a variable inside another is in an array when the variable is enclosed in the key's brackets like `[$var]`.

You could store your values in an associative array, and reference them like so:

```
declare -A arr
arr[dd01]="1"
arr[aa]="01"
arr[bb]="dd${arr[aa]}"
echo ${arr[${arr[bb]}]}
```

Using arrays like this may be more convoluted for this example than referencing the variable name using `${!bb}` syntax, but if you need to do this while keeping different sets of variables that may need to reference each other, creating an associative array may make more organizational sense.

Comment: While `$$` is a special parameter, it doesn't fully explain why `${$foo}` would fail to expand to the value of the variable named by `$foo`.

Comment: Correct.  `$$` builtin variable was only the causing the error when trying to expand the variable without the use of curly braces.  Please see updated post.

Comment: This is a very convoluted way of avoiding the indirect parameter expansion syntax.

Comment: There's no doubt doing `${!foo}` is simpler, but it might make more sense to create an associative array if you're using multiple variable sets that need to reference each other like is suggested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code example as follows which gives you the value of 1 which is what you are trying to achieve.

```
#!/bin/bash
dd01="1"
aa="01"
bb="dd$aa"
echo $[$bb]
```

Comment: Arithmetic evaluation will work, except when "dd01" is not a number

Comment: I think I will try your solution. I indeed want to have the value of dd01 = (1). In the original code it will be a string instead of a  value. So 01 instead of 1. Thank all for the help. It will help me further on the good direction.

Comment: `$[...]` is an obsolete syntax; use `$((...))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
dd=1234567890aAbBcC
aa="11"
echo ${dd:(aa-1):1}
```

Appearantly 1 is the 0 position and aa can also be like 01 and still work!

Thank for all the advices.

I found my answer here:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
dd01="1"
aa="01"
bb="dd$aa"
eval echo \$$bb
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the '$' operator to access the value of a variable.  For example...

```
d = 'Hi'
e = ' there '
f = 'friend.'
foo = '$d$e$f'
```

This would cause the value of foo to be 'Hi there friend.'

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think what he wants is an indirect variable reference; i.e. he wants to interpret a variable's value as the name of another variable and then get that latter value.

Answer (score -4):

[Use `eval`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
dd01="1"
aa="01"
eval bb=\$dd$aa
echo $bb
```

This script outputs the expected `1`.